# Need an idea on, how to open selected folder inside a JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I've looked it up everywhere, but can't find anything close to relevant... I just simply want to open the selected directory inside the JFileChooser, when the directory gets scanned of all files contained within, with the button click listed below.

Here's my code:

```
private void jBtnIncarcaMapaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jBtnIncarcaMapaActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jFileChooserModCom.getSelectedFile().isDirectory()) {
        try {
            File mapa = jFileChooserModCom.getSelectedFile();
            File[] arrayFisiereMapa = mapa.listFiles();
            for(File f : arrayFisiereMapa){
                listaFisiereMapa.add(f.getName());
            }
            arrayFisiere = new String[listaFisiereMapa.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < listaFisiereMapa.size(); i++){
                arrayFisiere[i] = listaFisiereMapa.get(i);
            }
            Arrays.sort(arrayFisiere);
            jListModCom.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
                String[] strings = arrayFisiere;
                public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
                public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
            });
            jFileChooserModCom.rescanCurrentDirectory();
        } catch(NullPointerException ex) {
            jLabelAvertismenteModCom.setText("<html><center>Nu ai ales<br> nici o mapa!</center><html/>");
        }
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_jBtnIncarcaMapaActionPerformed
```

And the specific JFileChooser settings:

```
jFileChooserModCom.setCurrentDirectory(new File(siluriNoi));
jFileChooserModCom.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
jFileChooserModCom.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
jFileChooserModCom.rescanCurrentDirectory();
```

Comment: Nobody? No ideas? Nothing? 

Comment: It’s not clear what you want to do. [`setCurrentDirectory(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory(java.io.File))?

Comment: @Holger So I have a JFileChooser displayed inside a JPanel in a Swing app... the user can click-select any directory or file, within the JFileChooser... but if the selected item happens to be a directory, then it can get scanned of all files that it contains, with the help of the button listed above, when I click this button, I also want to open the selected directory, to display the files inside, using(within) the same JFileChooser.

Comment: And doesn’t `setCurrentDirectory(…)` do that?

Comment: @Holger  Thanks man, that helped! Omg, I can't believe how simple it was...

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I've seen your previous answer regarding the Swing GUI builder... other members here, have also given the exact same advice, thank you all. I will take it in to account, when starting future projects, but for now I will keep using the IDE integrated GUI builder, as time falls short and I can't afford the luxury of writing the Swing GUI code all by myself, as the project size is considerable and I'm building it all alone! For the first experience ever, I think I'm doing pretty good! I've learned tons of new stuff since I started...